# How worked with large shapefile using sharpmap?

Tags: c#, shapefile, sharpmap

I use sharpmap for working with shapefile. Now shape file is big and sharpmap take a long time to loading layers. Please tell me how i can speed up working with shapefile.

Answer (score 0):

You can import it into a database and query only the parcels which you need to display instead of loading all the parcel data at once. I use a small windows form application to convert shapefiles into database byte data. If you want I can share you the code. (Works only for Shp file types)